# How to call Controller method of type HttpPost from Jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a controller function in MVC called `UpudateFingerprintStatus` from my jquery script. This is a `PUT` call because i'm updating the status of the desired object. I'm getting a `404 error` when i'm trying to call this method.

Here is my JS code:

```
    function updateStatus(statusId, fingerprintId, isDeleted, userId) {
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure you wish to change the Fingerprint Status?");
    if (confirm) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Tools/FingerprintTool/UpdateFingerprintStatus",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                userId: userId,
                statusId: parseInt(statusId),
                fingerprintId: fingerprintId,
                isDeleted: isDeleted
            }),
            sucess: function(resp) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(resp) {
                alert("Failure" + resp.description);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my Controller method:

```
 [HttpPut]
        public JsonResult UpdateFingerprintStatus(int userId, int statusId, int fingerprintId, int isDeleted)
        {
            var response = _driver.UpdateFingerprintGrantById(userId, fingerprintId, isDeleted, statusId);
            return Json(response.Note);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this help?

http://serverfault.com/questions/93424/how-to-enable-put-and-delete-in-iis7

Comment: Can you please change the parameters to  small as the controller and ajax call parameters are not matching.eg(UserId: userId, to userId: userId)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @Krish, The `DefaultModelBinder` is **not** case sensitive

Comment: try adding  `processData: false` to the jquery ajax attribute

Comment: /*GET*/ //try this method also
`$.ajax({
    url: '/User/Contains',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',    //replace /json to the urlenoded
    data: { name: 'Rintu', email: 'Rintu@gmial.com' },                  // data is not json
    async: true,
    processData: true,                                                  //important to use it as true
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});`

Comment: try 2 things 1. change PUT to POST in both jQuery and controller. Then in jQuery change the case of the parameters to match with case in controller method.

Comment: @JSantosh I tried this, but nothing worked. I keep getting a `404` error

Comment: Also I edited the questoin with the correct casing for the variable names

Comment: I think the issue is with JSON.stringify.  Try just using the object instead.

Comment: So for the `data` field, just get rid of the `stringy` method?

Comment: @aelstonjones, that didn't change anything, still have the `404` error

Comment: Also, my service doesn't run on IIS, so IIS isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

When we send post , put request it sends complex data type in body so to bind that complex data you need to create class in which all properties should have same name as you sending from front-end.

```
public class FingerprintStatus{
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public int FingerprintId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

}
    [HttpPut]
            public JsonResult UpdateFingerprintStatus(FingerprintStatus model)
            {
                var response = _driver.UpdateFingerprintGrantById(model.UserId, model.FingerprintId, model.IsDeleted, model.StatusId);
                return Json(response.Note);
            }
```

Comment: I do not understand. This is currently what I have?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function updateStatus(statusId, fingerprintId, isDeleted, userId) {
    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure you wish to change the Fingerprint Status?");
    if (confirm) {
        var domain = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
        var url = domain + "/Tools/FingerprintTool/UpdateFingerprintStatus";

        var dataContract = {
            userId: userId,
            statusId: parseInt(statusId),
            fingerprintId: fingerprintId,
            isDeleted: isDeleted
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataContract,
            sucess: function(resp) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(resp) {
                alert("Failure" + resp.description);
            }
        });
    }
}

[HttpPut]
public JsonResult UpdateFingerprintStatus(int userId, int statusId, int fingerprintId, int isDeleted)
{
    var response = _driver.UpdateFingerprintGrantById(userId, fingerprintId, isDeleted, statusId);
    return Json(response.Note);
}
```